# PHP URL Rewriting from local host via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I am using Wamp and i am new to url rewriting what i want to do is to convert this

```
localhost/webtv/video/?ID=14&CH=30
```

To:

```
localhost/webtv/channel name/video title/
```

where `/webtv/` = the root of my website on `localhost` and `ID` = the **video id** and `CH` = the **channel id**

Do i have to query the titles of the video and the channel or what and whatever solution you will give me will work on locahost as on the server ?

Thank you so much

Comment: You should start by renaming the windows directory name "channel name" to "channelname", "video title" to "videotitle" to save your time.

Comment: Usually, if your rewriting gets more complicated or would need a database connection, one would just rewrite _all_ urls inside `/webtv/...` that don't point to an actual file or directory to a script, which reads in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and just queries the database for existance of that video. If it doesn't exist, this script is also responsible for generating either a `404` of `410`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, You need to query the title and channel form url instead of ids.
How user can know id of the video in your table.Reverse is possible Get the title of the video and match with the id in mysql table.

For url rewrite make sure you had enable mod_rewrite in wamp

The url will for getting video title and channel is

```
localhost/webtv/video/?channel=channel_name&video=video_title
```

In .htaccess write below code.

```
RewriteRule webtv/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /webtv/video/?channel=$1&video=$2
```

Put htaccess in root (i.e) www directory.

Comment: Make sure you enable the `mod_rewirte` in `httpd.conf` and restart the wampp. Try put the `.htaccess` file in `c:\www\webtv\` directory.